# How do we prove that $A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid 4x - 3y < 5\}$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that the set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 4x - 3y < 5\}$ is open.

Looking the inequality, we know that $A$ is the set of points above the line $s: 4x-3y-5=0$, so for an arbitrary point $P(x_0,y_0) \in A$, we can calculate the distance from $P$ to $s$ by

\begin{align*}
d(P,s) & = \dfrac{|4x_0-3y_0-5|}{5}\\
& = \delta
\end{align*}

Now we can construct an open ball $B$ with center in $P$ with radius $r$, where $r < \delta$, i.e.,

$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 < r^2$

Now I need to show that $B \subset A$, and from here I got stuck.

I thought about, let $P_1(x_1,y_1) \in B$ and show that $P_1 \in A$, but I don't know what to do.

Looking this in the plane it's pretty simple to realize that $B \subset A$, but I wanted to begin in the equation $(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2 < r^2$ and somehow conclude that $4x_1 - 3y_1 < 5$. Is it necessary or can I just use the geometric argument? the geometric argument is cool, but not strong enough I think. Thanks for any tips

Comment: The plane is divided into three disjoint regions
$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 4x-3y\lt5\}$

$B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 4x-3y=5\}$

$C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 4x-3y\gt5\}$

If $P=(x,y)\in A$ then the distance from $P$ to the line $B$ is equal to a number  $d\gt0$. It follows that, for example, the ball centered at $P$ and radius $\dfrac d2$ is contained in $A$ so $A$ is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x,y) = 4x - 3y - 5$, which is continuous because it is a polynomial. Then $A = f^{-1}(-\infty,0)$, which is open because it is the preimage of an open set according to a continuous function.

Hopefully this helps!